# $|G|=8$ finite abelian group such that there is only 2 solutions for $x^2=e$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$|G|=8$ finite abelian group such that there is only $2$ solutions for $x^2=e$ , prove $G$ is cyclic.
**My try :**
Assume that $G$ is not cyclic , since $\forall g\in G : o(g)\in \{1,2,4,8\}$ then $o(g)\ne 8$
The first solution for the equation is $e$ because $e^2=e$
By Cauchy theorem we get that $2|8 \rightarrow \exists c\in G \rightarrow o(c)=2$
If exists another element of order $2$ for example $k\in G$ then we have one more solution which means $k=g$ or $k=e$
so $c$ is unique element of order $2$.

And here I'm stuck , by assumption all remaining elements need to be of order $4$, but if we have an element of order $4$ - say $w$ then $G=\{e,g,w,w^3\}$ and we need another element of order $4$.....

Any clues ? maybe some easier way to prove it or a contradiction perhaps (I couldn't find one).
Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Let $x$ be the nontrivial element of order $2$. Let $y \in G$ not $e$ or $x$: what can you say about $y^2$? Now find $z$ an element not a power of $y$, what can you say about $z^2$, then $yz^{-1}$?

Comment: No group has exactly two elements of order two. See **Exercise 4.61** of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)".*

Comment: the group in question has only one

Comment: @Mindlack $y^2 \ne e$ because $o(y)=4$ , but $y^2$ is also a solution so $y^2=g$ ($o(g)=2$) , $z^2 \ne e$ too and $o(z)=4$ so $z^2=g=y^2 \rightarrow yz^-1=zy^3$

Comment: @Shaun I have proved that there is only $1$ element of order $2$

Comment: Let $x$ be the non-identity solution. Because $G$ is abelian, squaring is a homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to itself. The kernel of $f$ is thus $\{e,x\}$, so the image, call it $H$, is a subgroup of order four. Therefore there is an element of order two in the image. We can conclude that $x\in H$, so there exists $y\in G$ such that $y^2=x$. Thinking about the restriction of $f$ to $H$ shows that we can find such an element $y\in H$ as well. So $y=z^2$ for some $z\in G$. It follows that $z$ is of order eight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $x$ be the unique element of order 2. and $H=<x>$ .
$G/H$ is a group of order 4. we will prove that G/H is cyclic.

if all the elements of $G/H$ have order of 2 or less, then G/H is of the form $\{H,yH,zH,yzH\}$ where $y,z$ are elements of $G$ that are not in $H$. so $y^2$ and $z^2$ are in $H$. none can be equal to $e$ since $x$ is the unique element of order 2, so both of them are equal to $x$ then $y^2=z^2=x$ so $(yz)^2=e$ then $yz=x$ thus $y=z$ contradiction.

then $G/H$ has an element of order 4 which proves the existence of an element $y$ in $G$ such that $yH$ has order 4 in $G/H$ thus $y^4=x$($y^4$ cannot be equal to e since we will have $y^2=e$ or $y^2=x$ which both give $yH$ is of order 2 in $G/H$ contradiction   ) so $y$ has order 8 in G. which means G is cyclic

Comment: because the quaternion group is not abelien to begin with ?

Comment: Thank you ,I have read it and its close to what I did but didn't post (I assumed there is another element of order 2 and proved we get a contradiction and then assumed for element of order 4), I didn't write it here because it's pretty long and confusing so of course I prefer your way of thinking. Nice proof

Comment: @Mike because $(yz)^2=y^2z^2=x^2=e$

Comment: the group is abelien

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle G=\{e,a_{1} ,a_{2} ,\cdots ,a_{7} \}$ be a finite abelian group of order $\displaystyle 8$. There must exist an element of order $\displaystyle 2$. WLOG, let $\displaystyle o( a_{1}) =2$.

Solutions to $\displaystyle x^{2} =e$ are $\displaystyle x=e$ and $\displaystyle x=a_{1}$ only.$\tag A$

Suppose on the contrary that $\displaystyle G$ is not cyclic and so by Lagrange's theorem: $\displaystyle o( a_{i}) \in \{1,2,4\}\ $for all $\displaystyle i\in \{1,2,3,...,7\}$. Note that $\displaystyle o( a_{i}) \neq 2,1$ for any $\displaystyle i\geq 2$. Because that will contradict our $\displaystyle ( A) .$

It follows that $\displaystyle o( a_{i}) =4$ for all $\displaystyle i\geq 2$. Given any $\displaystyle i\geq 2$ (say $\displaystyle a_{2}$ WLOG as G is abelian), we have $\displaystyle a_{2} ,a_{2}^{2} ,a_{2}^{3}$ as distinct. Note that $\displaystyle o\left( a_{2}^{2}\right) =2$ and so $\displaystyle a_{2}^{2} =a_{1}$ and the similar idea gives $\displaystyle a_{i}^{2} =a_{1}$ for all $\displaystyle i$.

Now for any $\displaystyle j,k\geq 2$(say $\displaystyle j=2,\ k=3$ for example): $\displaystyle |\langle a_{2} \rangle \langle a_{3} \rangle |=\frac{16}{|\langle a_{2} \rangle \cap \langle a_{3} \rangle |}$

Now here: denominator can't be $\displaystyle 1$ as $ $$\displaystyle \langle a_{2} \rangle \langle a_{3} \rangle $ is subset of $\displaystyle G$.

If the denominator is $\displaystyle 2$ then it follows that: $\displaystyle a_{2} ,a_{2}^{3} ,a_{3}^{3} ,a_{3}$ are distinct and that $\displaystyle \left( a_{3}^{3}\right)^{2} =a_{3}^{2} =e$, which contradicts $\displaystyle ( A)$. So now denominator must be $\displaystyle 4$ that is, $\displaystyle \langle a_{j} \rangle =\langle a_{i} \rangle $ for all $\displaystyle i\geq j\geq 2$. Following this, $\displaystyle G$ should have $\displaystyle 1+1+2=4$ elements only.

But this is also not possible as $\displaystyle G$ has $\displaystyle 8$ elements.

Therefore, by contradiction $\displaystyle G$ must be cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that an abelian group $G$ is not cyclic and has exactly one element $x$ of order 2.

Then there are 6 elements of order 4 in $G$, and for each element $y$ of order 4, so is $y^3$, and $(y^3)^3=y$. So from this it follows that the order-4 elements can be written $\{a,a^3,b,b^3,c,c^3\}$, for some $a,b,c$.
As $y^2$ is of order 2 for $y$ that is order 4, and there is exactly one order-2 element in $G$, it follows that $y^2=x$ for each such $y$ that is of order 4. So $a^2=b^2=c^2=x$ for $a,b,c$ as above.

Now, $a^2=x$ gives $ab \not = a^2 = x$, and in particular $ab\not=x$. But then $(ab)^2=abab=a^2b^2 = x^2=e$, which implies $ab$ of order-2, contradicting that $x$ is the only order-2 element of $G$. So we arrive at a contradiction. Thus $G$ must indeed be cyclic if $G$ is abelian, of order 8, and has exactly one element of order 2.

**There are however nonabelian groups $G$ of order 8 and
with exactly one element of order 2 though.** Consider the following group $G$, generated by 3 elements $a,b,c$: The set of elements of $G$ are $\{e,a,b,c,x,a^3,b^3,c^3\}$, and the following relations hold:

$a^4=b^4=c^4=e$;
$a^2=b^2=c^2=x$; $e=x^2$; $ab=c$; $ba=c^3$; $ca = b$; $bc=a$; $ba=c^3$; $ac=b^3$; $cb=a^3$.

Comment: you forgot that the group in question is abelien

Comment: @Laassila souhayl Yes I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

As there are total 5 groups of order 8 in which two are non-abelian and 3 are abelian
i.e.
|G|=8 then G can be Quaternion group$(Q_8)$, or $D_4$ these two are non-abelian groups
and G can be $Z_4+Z_2$ or $Z_2+Z_2+Z_2$ or $Z_8$ these are 3 abelian groups of order 8.
And given that G is abelian and $x^2=e$ has only 2 solutions, that is $|x|=1$ or $|x|=2$
and we know the identity is the only element is of order $1$ in G that means there is a unique element of order 2 in G
so the only possibility of G is $Z_8$ and clearly, this is a finite cyclic group of order 8.
Hence G is a cyclic group.